# const in template argument

Tags: c++, templates, constants

What is the effect of the `const` keyword in this template?

```
template <class T, int const ROWNUM, int const COLNUM> 
class Matrix
```

Does it mean that this template only accept a `const` as parameter? If so, is there a way to pass a variable as the `COLNUM` and `ROWNUM`?

(when I try to pass a variable as the COLNUM for the template, it gives an error: "IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value")

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's ignored:

> `[C++11: 14.1/4]:` A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally *cv-qualified*) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.
>
> `[C++11: 14.1/5]:` [ *Note:* Other types are disallowed either explicitly below or implicitly by the rules governing the form of *template-arguments* (14.3). *—end note* ] **The top-level *cv-qualifiers* on the *template-parameter* are ignored** when determining its type.

The same wording is present at the same location in C++03.

This is partially because template arguments must be known at compile-time anyway. So, whether you have the `const` there or not, [you *may not* pass some variable value](http://ideone.com/VFpoLr):

```
template <int N>
void f()
{
    N = 42;
}

template <int const N>
void g()
{
    N = 42;
}

int main()
{
    f<0>();
    g<0>();

    static const int h = 1;
    f<h>();
    g<h>();
}
```

> prog.cpp: In function ‘**void f() [with int N = 0]**’:
>   prog.cpp:15:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:4: error: **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘**void g() [with int N = 0]**’:
>   prog.cpp:16:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:10: error: **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘**void f() [with int N = 1]**’:
>   prog.cpp:19:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:4: error: **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘**void g() [with int N = 1]**’:
>   prog.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:10: error: **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**

Comment: it's weird, since when I try to pass a variable as the COLNUM for the template, it gives an error: "IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value"

Comment: @Chin: Why is that weird? Template arguments must be known at compile-time, because that's when templates are expanded.

Comment: I see. So is there a way to do it at run-time?

Comment: @Chin: Sure - just use normal function arguments. Perhaps arguments to a class constructor.

Comment: there is a difference between const function parameters and const template parameters though. The latter's const is ignored when you use `decltype` on them (because it is ignored "when determining their type"). The const of the former is not ignored by `decltype`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: True. In fact, [they're not ignored in that case at all](http://ideone.com/nGSDqO).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So there is no way to initialize a template using a variable?

Comment: @Chin: No, that would make no sense.

Comment: Well you sort of can via an abomination: branching pseudo switch that instantiates the type with a constant, then calls a functor with the instance.  Not hard to write, just almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk: Can you give an example?

Comment: `template<typename F> void toy(bool b, F f) { if (b) f.template do<true>(); else f.template do<false>(); }` effectively applies variable b to template F::do.  Doing this for all int is doable by say switching on bits and building the resulting compile time constant before instantiation.  Ugly as sin hack, and generates a stupid amount of binary.  But it effectively gets you a type whose value is determined by a variable value.  Did I mention stupid large resulting binary?  I should do it again.  Syntax above probably wrong: writing this on a phone.  :)

Comment: @Yakk: No it doesn't. `F::do<true>` and `F::do<false>` have constant arguments. That you've chosen to _use_ one or the other at runtime based upon some variable is subtly yet also monumentally not the same thing! You might as well claim that `const int x` isn't necessarily `const` because you can write `const int x = 5; cout << (rand() ? x : 42);`

Comment: Yes.  That is why the words 'effectively' and 'sort of' where used instead of 'actually'.  You can create a function `f(x, y)` such that `y::operator()<x>()` is called, which effectively (and not actually) does variable substitution into a template.

Comment: @Yakk: OK but he said "initialize a template" not "invoke a function [which may be a template instantiation]" ;)

Comment: `#include <iostream>
template<int n> struct bob { bob() { std::cout << "bob" << n << " reporting in\n"; }; }; struct bar { template<int n> void Do() const { bob<n> b; }; }; template<int n=0,int bit=9> struct foo { template<typename F> void Do(unsigned int x,F&& f) { if ((x>>bit)&1) { foo<(n<<1)|1,bit-1>().Do(x,f); } else { foo<(n<<1),bit-1>().Do(x,f); }; }; }; template<int n> struct foo<n,-1> { template<typename F> void Do(unsigned int x,F&& f) const { f.template Do<n>(); }; }; template<typename F> void mojo(int x, F&& f) { foo<>()(x,f); } int main() { mojo(7,bar()); }` 
instantiates bob<7> ;)

Comment: @Yakk: Pfft :P BTW line 44 doesn't look right (as laid out [here](http://ideone.com/sVVvHS))

Comment: Damnit!  Was shaving characters off, and missed a `.Do`.  `#include<iostream>
template<int n>struct bob{bob(){std::cout<<"bob"<<n<<" reporting in\n";};};struct bar{template<int n>void Do()const{bob<n>b;};};template<int n=0,int bit=10>struct foo{template<typename F>void Do(unsigned int x,F&& f){if ((x>>bit)&1){foo<(n<<1)|1,bit-1>().Do(x,f);}else{foo<(n<<1),bit-1>().Do(x,f);};};};template<int n>struct foo<n,-1>{template<typename F>void Do(unsigned int x,F&& f)const{f.template Do<n>();};};template<typename F>void mojo(int x,F&& f){foo<>().Do(x,f);}int main(){mojo(7,bar());}` -- there.

Comment: @Yakk: You've got it (http://ideone.com/vxJi8u)

Answer (score 3):

`const` is not required in your case

for instance, both classes `Matrix_A` and `Matrix_B` below are the same for the compiler *point of view*. `const` here is just to enforce the fact that `ROWNUM` and `COLNUM` are constant for humans *point of view*, but not required.

```
template <class T, int const ROWNUM, int const COLNUM> 
class Matrix_A 
{
};

template <class T, int       ROWNUM, int       COLNUM> 
class Matrix_B
{
};
```

Moreover following class `Matrix_C` also specify similar constant variables `ROWNUM` and `COLNUM` in another way:

```
template <class T> 
class Matrix_C
{
   static int const ROWNUM = 5;
   static int const COLNUM = 20;
};

// the following three objects use constant variables ROWNUM and COLNUM
Matrix_A<bool,5,20> a;
Matrix_B<bool,5,20> b;
Matrix_C<bool>      c;
```

Comment: [That's the case whether `const` is present or not](http://ideone.com/FjOWyV), so it's not the `const`'s doing.

Comment: you are right. I am wrong :-(

Comment: [Your example does not compile](http://ideone.com/ceTboa).

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit for your compilation test ;-) Now everything should be ok. Cheers