# Define constant using function from another method and #define

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to define a constant using function from another method and `#define`?

For example, I have in file foo.cpp a method that returns an int:

```
int foo() { return 2; }
```

In my bar.cpp, I want to have something like

```
#define aConstant foo()
```

Is it possible? Is there a way to do it?

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010)

EDIT: `constexpr` doesn't work since I'm using VS 2010, so any other idea?

Comment: have you read up on the extern keyword? that might have a solution

Comment: I'm not saying it's the best way, but have you even tried it? http://ideone.com/XYGPmA

Comment: A note about `constexpr` (which is probably what you want), it's C++11 only.

Comment: Still [trying to pass a variable as a template argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435235/const-in-template-argument), are we?

Comment: yeah :) I'm looking for a trick or something :)

Comment: you cannot use a runtime computed value for a template parameter.

Comment: but if I can somehow `#define` a variable using the preprocessor, that variable's value is computed before the actual compilation of the template begins, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it

```
constexpr int foo() { return 2; }
```

Then in the other unit

```
static constexpr int aConstant = foo();
```

Comment: No :-( [This table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) (from the Apache Stdcxx project) says that Visual Studio (MSVC) does not yet support it (check the 7th line)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I don't have my VM available due to a broken PC at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything inherently wrong about saying `static int const a = bar();` anywhere in your code at namespace scope. It's just that unless `bar` is `constexpr`, the initialization will happen during the *dynamic initialization phase*. This may lead to certain ordering problems, but it's not by itself broken, and subsequent use of `a` will be as efficient as you can imagine.

Alternatively you could make the function a macro:

```
#define TIMESTWO(n) (n * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Visual C++ 2010 does not support feature `constexpr` brought by C++11 as you can see it on [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) (from the Apache Stdcxx project): MSVC (MicroSoft Visual studio C/C++ compiler) does not yet support it (check the 7th line).

However you can still keep your `foo()` body in `foo.cpp` file and use an intermediate global variable:

```
inline int foo() { return 2; }
const int aConstant = foo();
```

Then in `bar.cpp` file:

```
extern const int aConstant;

void bar()
{
   int a = 5 * aConstant;
}
```

If you have configured Visual C++ to allow inlining (this is the default), then `aConstant` will be initialized at compilation time. Else, `foo()` will be called to initialize `aConstant` at run-time, but on start-up (before the `main()` function is called). So this is much better than to call `foo()` each time the `const` returned value is used.

Comment: can you specify which cpp file and which header file in term of foo and bar?

Comment: al-right @Chin I have indicated the file names. Is it OK? Chhers ;-)

Comment: so will it somehow solve my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435235/const-in-template-argument , ie passing a variable to a template?

Comment: Yep no problem but your function `foo()` must always return `2`. I do not know what you are really coding, so if it still fails, then you can ask for another question... good luck ;-)