# Effects of a const base class

Tags: c++, constants, derived-class

What is the actual effect of the following construct:

```
class Base { /* ... */ };

template<class T>
class Derived : public T { /* ... */ };

int main() {
    Derived<const Base> d;
    // ...
}
```

Does the `Derived` class only have access to the `const`-part of the interface of `Base`? My first tests indicate that there's actually no effect at all. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: I think, that the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13435319/945183

Comment: I think these questions refer to different things: The linked ones are about template *declarations* of the form `template<const int N> struct test;` and my question is about template *instantiations* whose applied parameters are `const` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `const` is ignored, because if you try to write

```
class Derived : public const Base
```

the program [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/JLJCVV).

**EDIT:**

[frozenkoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599926/frozenkoi) gave the relevant part of the standard in the comments:

> "A typedef-name (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a class-name. If a typedef-name that names a cv-qualified class type is used where a class-name is required, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. A typedef-name shall not be used as the identifier in a class-head." §9.1

Comment: You're right, you can't write it explicitly. I guess it's like `void func() { return void(); }` - writing it explicitly it's completely useless but in the context of templates important as a corner case.

Comment: I think it has more to do with `const` being ignored when declaring the type than being ignored in the class declaration. (no c++ standard at hand) but it's along these lines: "The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored when determining its type" §14

Comment: I’m not convinced because that’s just a syntax issue; this compiles: http://ideone.com/ik41t3

Comment: @KonradRudolph note that your sample goes through a typedef, and I think that ends up ignoring the `const` too.

Comment: I think in that case the relevant part in the spec is "A typedef-name (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a class-name. If a typedef-name that names a cv-qualified class type is used where a class-name is required, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. A typedef-name shall not be used as the identifier in a class-head." §9.1 (I have a draft version with me, might be innacurate)

Comment: @frozenkoi A typedef in general definitely does *not* ignore the `const`, as is easily verifiable by declaring a variable using the typedef, and attempting to modify it. But I think your standard quote is actually relevant here, put it in an answer.