# passing a variable as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template node class that takes an integer parameter. I also have a tree class that creates a node and passes its constructor argument as the argument for the node template.

**Tree.cpp**

```
Tree::Tree(int n) {
    this->n = n;
    root = new Node<n>(); // compiler error
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
Tree *tree = new Tree(2);
```

My compiler complains that *‘n’ is not a constant expression*. How do I successfully pass `n` to my node class?

Comment: The compiler is going to need to know what `n` is in advance. How are you going to expect it to instantiate the right template if it's only settled in the distant future? "Not a constant expression" is what you need to take away from this. Short answer: You can't. Long answer involves knowing what `Node` is doing with `n`.

Comment: You cannot "pass" `n` to your Node class, because template parameters are not passed to templates, the way that a function parameter is passed to a function. A template, and a function, are fundamentally different things. C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Comment: templates only work with values that are known at compile time. `n` is not know inside `Tree:Tree` until runtime. Therefore it can't be used with a template. You'd have to make `Tree` itself a template and pass `n` as a template parameter.

Comment: Template argument must be decided at compile time. The passing n may vary in runtime, so compiler is unable to generate the new `Node<n> class` based on the n.

Comment: I thought `n` is known during compile time because it is 2.

Comment: `n` is not `2` when `Tree.cpp` is being compiled, now is it? It's only set as `2` during `main.cpp`, and there's absolutely no guarantee those two will ever meet. That's up to the linker.

Comment: `n` that's passed to `Tree`'s constructor can be any value that fits into an `int`. It is not 2. It can be any `int` value, and the constructor must work for any value of `n`. But because you need a constant value in order to instantiate a template, you simply can't instantiate a template using a variable, in this manner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435235/const-in-template-argument

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do like that.

`n` is known at compile time, but it is not known as a template argument. Since you need `n` in your `Tree` constructor, you could make your `Tree` class a template too.

Answer (score 0):

Make your constructor a template one:

```
struct Base
{

};
template <int N>
struct Node : Base
{

};

class Tree 
{
public:

    template <int N>
    struct size
    {
    };

    template<int N> Tree(size<N>) {
        this->n = N;
        root = new Node<N>();
    }

    int n;
    Base* root;
};

int main() {

    Tree t = Tree(Tree::size<2>());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how would you invoke such a constructor exactly? `n` must be deducible.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it cannot work, for `n` must be known at compile-time.
You can make it a constructor template parameter. Unfortunately, in this case, it cannot be explicitly given and must be deducible. It's a matter of an ugly syntax that works anyway.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct BaseNode {};

template<int n>
struct Node: BaseNode {};

struct Tree {
    template<int n>
    Tree(std::integral_constant<int, n>)
        : n{n}, root{new Node<n>()}
    {}

    int n;
    BaseNode *root;
};

int main() {
    Tree tree{std::integral_constant<int, 2>{}};
}
```

Note that you can easily work around the ugly syntax with a factory method:

```
struct Tree {
    template<int n>
    Tree(std::integral_constant<int, n>)
        : n{n}, root{new Node<n>()}
    {}

    template<int n>
    static Tree create() {
        return Tree{std::integral_constant<int, n>{}};
    }

    int n;
    BaseNode *root;
};

// ...

Tree tree = Tree::create<2>();
```

Another possible solution is to provide a `Node` as an argument and deduce `n` from it:

```
struct Tree {
    template<int n>
    Tree(Node<n> *node)
        : n{n}, root{node}
    {}

    // ...
};
```

Or use a two steps initialization and be able to explicitly pass your `n` as a template parameter:

```
struct Tree {
    Tree(): n{0}, root{nullptr} {}

    template<int n>
    void init() {
        this->n = n;
        root = Node<n>;
    }

    int n;
    BaseNode *root;
};

// ...

Tree tree{};
tree.init<2>();
```